# ActionScript - indexOf Vector.<Object>?

Tags: actionscript-3, search, object, vector, indexing

why does the following `indexOf(searchElement:T, fromIndex:int = 0):int` not find the object and return `-1`?

```
var v:Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>();
v.push({name:"Geoffrey", age:32});

trace(v.indexOf({name:"Geoffrey", age:32}));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer is that `Vector.indexOf()` searches by reference.  In your code you have created two, completely separate objects; they may look identical to you, but that's because you're a human :)

```
const v : Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>();
const geoff : Object = { name: "Geoffrey", age: 32 };

v.push(geoff);
const index : uint = v.indexOf(geoff);

trace("Geoff is at index: " + index);  // Traces "Geoff is at index: 0".
```

If you want to find the index of an object based on its properties you will want to use a `fori` loop.

```
const people : Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>();
people.push({ name: "Jonny", age: 28 });
people.push({ name: "Geoffrey", age: 32 });

const needle : String = "Geoffrey";

var index : int = -1;
for (var i : uint = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    if (people[i].name == needle) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

trace(needle + " found at index: " + index);
```

Comment: curse my humanity! :p  thanks for clearing this up for me, jonny.

Answer (score 2):

Because, according to the doc, "the item is compared to the Vector elements using strict equality (===).", and `{name:"Geoffrey", age:32} !== {name:"Geoffrey", age:32}`, however this would work:

```
var v:Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>();
var o:Object = {name:"Geoffrey", age:32};
v.push(o);

trace(v.indexOf(o));
```

Answer (score 2):

The `{}` "object literal" syntax creates a *new instance* of `Object` for each usage. The `indexOf()` method searches for the specified instance in the vector, and because you are using the object literal syntax twice, you are effectively creating two objects. The second one is not the same as the first one (which you pushed into the vector) and hence will not be found.